# WiFi Network Adapter disappears

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, network-adapter

SO I have a problem with my WI-Fi network adapter
I am running a Windows 10 PC
After using my PC for a few Hours (sometimes just few Minutes), I lose my Wifi connection trying to reactivating it the way-Fi icon does not respond to anything 
Searching where this problem is coming from I found that my PC is loosing connection the my WI-Fi Network adapter

I tried going to "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center -> change adapter settings", But I didn't find the WiFi Network Adabter
I tried also searching for it in the "Device Manager" But I still can't find it

After restarting My PC everything Come back to work normally, But only for a few Hours or Minutes then The Wifi stops Again!!
enter image description here
I have also tried to rollback my "Intel (R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260" Driver Update But I still have the same Problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after all I wasn't able to find where the problem is coming from.
I end up with resetting my Pc (Windows 10 -- Reset this PC (keep my files) --)
and the problem is gone now, everything work properly.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Intel 8260 is a good adapter.

1. The next time it is working, update the driver - there are new updates for it.
2. When it disappears, you cannot see it in Device Manager. If you are adept with small things, try re-seating the card (it plugs into a socket inside the computer). Ask a local computer store to do this if you would rather not.
3. If re-seating fails, then the card is likely defective.
4. You said later a USB wireless card works and the USB card can work even if the internal card does not. If you suspect Viruses (viruses do not normally kill a card) do a full scan with Windows 10 Defender

Comment: Hello, Thank you For your help

Well I will try to re-seat the Card but I don't think the problem is in the card 

I think ( I am not sure if this even exists ) that there is a Virus Which damages my Adapter driver

Well, When I opened my PC today, I disabled the card driver and I plugged an WIFI-USB ( I don't know how to call it ) , and installed it's driver
it worked properly for some while, then I tried disconnecting from my router and connecting to another, then everything stopped again.

Is it possible that a virus do something like this ?

thank you,and sorry about my language

Comment: If the USB wireless works, then main hardware is OK. And the USB card can work even if the internal card does not.  If you suspect viruses , do a full scan with Windows Defender

Comment: I tried about 3 or 4 anti-viruses But Everything looks good , no malwares, no Viruses, Nothing at all.

I forgot to mention that the problem occurs also If I try to turn on airplane mode.
or if the problem occur the airplane mode stops working also.

Comment: I am fairly sure the internal card has a hardware issue.